# EmberJS - Observe a computed property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Why the following codes are not equivalent?

With computed:

```
computed: Ember.computed('selected', function() {
    console.log('computed');
    return this.get('selected');
}),

observer1: Ember.observer('computed', function() {
    console.log('observer1');
}),

observer2: Ember.observer('selected', function() {
    console.log('observer2');
}),
```

With alias:

```
computed: Ember.computed.alias('selected'),

observer1: Ember.observer('computed', function() {
    console.log('observer1');
}),

observer2: Ember.observer('selected', function() {
    console.log('observer2');
}),
```

The first one only prints `observer2` and the second one prints `observer1` and `observer2`.

Comment: where are you setting or using `selected` property? give ember-twiddle it will help us to play

Comment: https://ember-twiddle.com/9889ca948285d7ef2cb75d8c6e5942b2?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Answer (score 1):

In the first one, `computed` is just a getter. So if you don't use `computed` in template or other places to react ASAP on changing, it's not called by changing `selected`.

But in second one, alias creates setter too. So if you change `selected`, `computed` changes after that quickly.

If you use `computed` in first one in a template, the same result comes.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to avoid using the computed only to `activate` it?

Comment: @Charles computed property is a property. and a property is just for carrying data, showing data. If you need some process when changing occurs, the observers are the right ones.

Comment: @Charles So activate means using the property here

Comment: I need the computed in the observer that's why I need both. It still seems odd to me.

Comment: @Charles Can you provide the real problem?

Comment: It don't remember my problem, I solve it in another way sorry. But it seems to be the same with `Ember.computed.and`...

Comment: In this twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/b5eaef8366d6a80b06fe50a5cc2511aa?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C Clicking `Check1` and `Check2` should automatically check `Check all`. This only works if `{{allChecked}}` in printed to the template however it's not needed. I need to add it to a comment.